# Implementing Flask-WhooshAlchemy using an Application Factory

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

If app is created in global scope

***__init__.py***

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
from app import views
```

This code down below in run.py  would be enuf to start using `whoosh_search` in ***views.py*** like `post = Post.query.whoosh_search(name, limit=3).all(`)

***run.py***

```
import os
from app import app


from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.moment import Moment

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask.ext.whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'post.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess string'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

manager = Manager(app)
moment = Moment(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    __searchable__ = ['body']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)

whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    manager.run()
```

So how to implement [Flask-WhooshAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/) using an [Application Factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/).

***__init__.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

How to register `app` in `whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)` with Application Factory so `whoosh_search` could be use in **views.py** like in last example.

Answer (score 0):

In your application factory function fx. after initializing all the apps, and before registering your blueprints. You should import your model and run whoosh_index. Something along the lines of:

```
  from .model import Post
  whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)
```